# Paypal developer account

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, paypal

I've been searching the whole day and unfortunately the documentation is not so organized and after reading most of it I'm still looking for answers so here's the deal:
- I already have a developer account, what I'm trying to do is a facebook app that allows my company to sell tickets to some shows, can I develop the app with my account and the money from that app instead of getting transfered into my account goes to other account, let's say the company's account? Or do I need to register the company's account as developer and then develop the APP with that account.

I've already read many starting guides and stuff like that but they're so many I am just confused with so much dispersed information.

I don't know if this information is useful but here are the steps made by the users in the facebook app, wich is inside a facebook page where the user must like the page first before access the app

-> then in the facebook app the user chooses the events and the number of tickets and proceed to payment

->the facebook app is inside page so is an iframe app, to prevent problems that may advert from that, I'm thinking of displaying a popup with the paypal process so the user is kept in the facebook app.

-> after the user is done with the payment my facebook app sends an email with the information to get the tickets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You developer account is only for the implementation. No money gets transferred from no account to none other. After implementation and making sure everything works fine You just switch the account to the company business account and go to production.

Also the implementation is done against the paypal dev, after it is finished it is switched to paypal production.